# in eclipse export jar database is not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a Swing application that uses msaccess database. 
The application runs fine on Eclipse, but when I run the packaged executable Jar, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

here is my code

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:cs");
```

please help me

Comment: You just have to put Driver Jar file with the executable jar.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?